# How to set the time to central time zone on Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++

I am trying to figure out how to set the time on the esp8266 board to Central Time Zone.

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
configTime(-5*3600, 3600, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");

time(&curr_time);
curr_tm = localtime(&curr_time);

char date_string[100];
char time_string[100];
char ampm_string[50];
char zone_string[50];

strftime(date_string, 50, "Today is %B %d, %Y", curr_tm);
strftime(time_string, 50, "Current time is %T", curr_tm);
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong or recommend a library I can use to achieve this?
Thank you!

Comment: Thank for pointing that out.  I updated my question to clock -> time.

Comment: I am sorry, `time()` is implemented [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/b08d282673055b4758cd73d3cd99573f619112a5/cores/esp8266/time.c#L80) on esp8266, good to know.

Comment: I thought that's what configTime() does?  It syncs the Arduino clock with the national servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
configTime(0, 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");
setenv("TZ", "CST6CDT,M3.2.0/02:00:00,M11.1.0/02:00:00", 1);  
tzset();
```

Comment: timezones are defined in TZ.h so: `configTime(TZ_America_Chicago, "pool.ntp.org");`